# Java - Class Field / Method getInt

Tags: java

I have an interface which contains only int values (so in essence, it is pretty similar to an enum).

I want to iterate the interface values, using the following piece of code:

```
for (Field x : MyInterface.class.getDeclaredFields())
{
    int y = x.getInt(x);
    // do something with 'y'...
}
```

The way I see it, either the getInt method can be static, or it doesn't need any arguments.

So why does this method need both 'this' and the additional argument?

Is there any plausible scenario for them to be different?

Comment: Try to pass `null` as argument: it should work too.

Comment: @sp00m: thanks... still doesn't answer my question though...

Comment: @barakmanos -  You cant have static methods in an interface..

Comment: @TheLostMind: I was asking about a method in the Field class. Please read the question more carefully.

Comment: @noone: I have an interface (not mine, so I cannot change it), and I am trying to iterate its int values using the (built-in) Field class. So I am asking a question on a method within the Field class, not about interfaces or classes in general. Thanks.

Comment: @barakmanos In this case my answer should still be valid and explain the actual meaning of that method and parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int y = x.getInt(x);
```

This is actually wrong and doesn't make any sense. The JavaDoc of `Field.getInt` says the following:

> Parameters:
>   obj - the object to extract the int value from
>
> Returns:
>   the value of the field converted to type int

A `Field` is "globally" defined for a class. If you want to access a value of a field of a certain *instance* of that class, then you need to supply that instance to the `getField(Object)` method.

It even goes further and says:

> Throws:
>
> IllegalArgumentException - if the specified object is not an instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying field (or a subclass or implementor thereof), or if the field value cannot be converted to the type int by a widening conversion.
>
> NullPointerException - if the specified object is null and the field is an instance field.

So you cannot provide `null` as it was suggested in the comments, *unless* the field is a `static` field. You can also not use the field itself (`x`) as the parameter, since it is not an instance of that class.

In your specific case, when a field is defined within an `interface`, all fields become `static final` automatically. Thus you can provide `null` as the parameter, because there is no further information needed.

But since this method of `Field` can also be used in other cases (non-static ones), there needs to be this parameter.

Comment: Please read the code within the question more carefully: 'x' is an instance of class Field. In order to call the getInt method, I have to use this instance, since the method is not static. So why is this method not static to begin with, or alternatively - why does it take an argument?

Comment: @barakmanos I did and answered it. I added some more specific information at the end of my answer, so it becomes more clear.

Comment: "the field itself (x) is not an instance of that class"? When I declare 'Field x', what class is 'x' an instance of?

Comment: @barakmanos x is an instance of `Field`, not `MyInterface` (which is the only accepted type in the non-static case. in the static case it doesn't matter, since it isn't used.)

Comment: so in class Field, why is the getInt method not static? What is the point in calling this method with an instance of Field and an additional argument? Under what scenario would you call it with an instance of Field and the required argument being different from each other?

Comment: @barakmanos You need to understand that your case is actually a very special case, since your fields are static. In this case you are right, and the additional argument is not needed (thus you can provide null or even the field itself) and it also isn't used. But the normal case is a non-static one. Then you need to understand that you could have two instances of the class. But you have only one `Field` instance. How would `Field` know which instance it should extract the field-value from? It cannot and thus you need to provide the instance as the additional parameter.